# JavaScript random trigger on event

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, eris-discord

I'm currently trying to code a Discord bot, and I'm trying to randomly do something when a user talks in chat, so it sometimes will trigger, and sometimes wont trigger, its **random**. I've looked all over and I found nothing, I'm using the Eris library in JavaScript. Thanks for the help! :D

**Link to Eris library:** [Eris Library For Discord](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs)

*Also, I just need to find out how to randomly trigger the event when a event happens, not asking for all the code, just the part to randomly trigger when a certain event happens.*

Comment: If true randomness isn't required, just use `Math.random`, as in something like `if ( Math.random() > 0.7 ) { do stuff..` when the event occurs ?

Comment: So loop a function containing that indefinitely and then sorta like that?

Comment: Loop? Did you have an event, more like -> https://jsfiddle.net/q9frjjab/3/

Comment: Ohhhh! I get it now, sorry for the confusion. Now I need to find out how to make it work together. Thank you so much for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something when anyone talks in chat, just set up a basic message listener like this:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    // your code here
});
```

Your code inside the listener will run every time a message is sent in the chat.

So to run a command randomly, do something like adeneo pointed out, like this:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.7) {
        // Run your command. For example, send a message back to the same channel like this:
        msg.channel.send('This is a message from the bot!');
    }
});
```

You can find more information about setting up a basic bot in the basic [Discord.js Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Comment: Im using the eris library. I believe I can make this work from what I got so far. Thank you so much <3 :D